# WordPress paths with GLOB PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, glob

hi I am using the code below to try and read a directory and display all the JPEGs from it but thanks to WordPress paths i'm coming unstuck:

```
<?php 
    $path = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $files = glob("homepageBottomPictures/*.*");
    var_dump($files);
    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) {
        $num = $files[$i];
        echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" class="homepageBtmImg">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    } 
    echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
?>
```

So in my theme directory i have a folder called homepageBottomPictures with JPEGs in them. What can i do? (At the moment, nothing is returned to $files)

Comment: Where is this php script in relation to `homepageBottomPictures/`? Same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`get_theme_root()  . get_template() . '/homepageBottomPictures/*.*'` to get your directory

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful, here is some code I wrote to get image files of a few types with a certain pattern in the filename. You could alter it a bit to pull only jpg's of any pattern.

```
function returnimages($dirname, $photo_id) {

        $pattern="(^".$photo_id."[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.jpg$)|(^".$photo_id."[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.png$)|(^".$photo_id."[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.jpeg$)|(^".$photo_id."[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
        $files = array();
        $curimage=0;

        if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(eregi($pattern, $file)){         //if this file is a matching image
                    $files[$curimage] = $dirname.$file;   //Save it in the array
                    $curimage++;
                }//end if
            }//end while

            closedir($handle);
        }//end if   
return($files);

}//end returnimages
```